# Create Function class in My Routine in Talend

Tags: java, function, talend, data-integration

**Anyone Can help me to fix my Java Function to use it in my Routine.**

The Function will **remove exponent** and put it in a **Float format**.

**This is the function :**

```
float amount = 3.53435E12;
java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("# .# ");
String s=df.format(amount );
System.out.println("amount = " + s);
```

it will **convert the number** format from this **3.53435E12** to this **3 534 350 000 000**

the result will be like this ---> **3 534 350 000 000**

Now i want to **create a function** in my Routine in order **to use it in Tmap with my column.**

Thanks.

Comment: First thing change the float to double

Answer (score 1):

In your routine named for Example  **MyRoutine**

```
 public static double convertNumber(double message) {
    
    java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("# .# ");
    String s=df.format(message );
    System.out.println("amount = " + s);
    return (Double.parseDouble(s))  ;

}
```

The in tMap simply call

```
MyRoutine.convertNumber(row1.amount)
```

Comment: Thank you Amine, i did like you told me , but i'm getting an error it says " cannot convert from void to Double"

Comment: Yes the code works fine now. But it didn't convert the value as i need it. the function should convert this "3.53435E12" to this " 3 534 350 000 000"

Comment: the problem in my function now . I don't know if you can help me to fix it. Thanks

Comment: I just converted your code as you mentionned in your question . You should tell also that your code is not working as the output wanted

Comment: your could use thing regular expressions

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/McrHgj/1/

Comment: You want your function to return a String :)